# Can't execute a sql query (mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql

the connection to the db works, but than the sql query fails (I have tried many variations with no success). Help would be appreciated.
This is my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","root","*****","bsr");
            if(! $con )
                {
                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
            $query = "INSERT INTO eden (username,password) VALUES ('aaa', 'ddd')";
            $retval = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            if(! $retval )
                {
                  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
```

result: "Could not enter data:"

Comment: Use `mysqli_error()` to check for an error message after your query.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now i can see that the problem was: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'1

Comment: so make your id (primary key) as auto_incremented.

Comment: Yea, iv'e just found the A_I button. Thank you :) BTW, how do i mark this topic as "solved"?

Comment: @user3425231, just answer your own question and tick it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO eden (username,password) VALUES ('aaa', 'ddd')";
$retval = $con -> query($query);

if(! $retval ){
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
```